# Reverse DNS does not contain the hostname error from MXToolBox

Tags: email-server, hostname, reverse-dns

I am not sure where I have gone wrong in my configuration but I am getting the error `Reverse DNS does not contain the hostname` for my domain `sparkdojo.com` I had the hosting company set the PTR record to `host2.sparkdojo.com` and all of the tests I have conducted using `dig` and `host` seem to return the correct information. I have waited 24 hours because I read somewhere that the results might be cached or need to propagate but still I am still getting the error. I am hoping someone with more knowledge can determine what is wrong.

UPDATE:

```
dig -x 162.254.149.186

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -x 162.254.149.186
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21705
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;186.149.254.162.in-addr.arpa.  IN  PTR


;; ANSWER SECTION:
186.149.254.162.in-addr.arpa. 43200 IN  PTR host2.sparkdojo.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
149.254.162.in-addr.arpa. 34369 IN  NS  rdns1.hivelocity.net.
149.254.162.in-addr.arpa. 34369 IN  NS  rdns2.hivelocity.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
rdns1.hivelocity.net.   74146   IN  A   199.193.113.131
rdns2.hivelocity.net.   74146   IN  A   199.193.113.132

;; Query time: 79 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat May 16 14:33:04 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 165
```

Host Command

```
host 162.254.149.186
186.149.254.162.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer host2.sparkdojo.com.
```

MXToolBox Transcript

```
Connecting to 162.254.149.186

220-host2.sparkdojo.com ESMTP Exim 4.85 #2 Sat, 16 May 2015 14:18:48 -0500 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail. [780 ms]
EHLO MXTB-PWS3.mxtoolbox.com
250-host2.sparkdojo.com Hello mxtb-pws3.mxtoolbox.com [64.20.227.133]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP [655 ms]
MAIL FROM:<supertool@mxtoolbox.com>
250 OK [655 ms]
RCPT TO:<test@example.com>
550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. 
550-mxtb-pws3.mxtoolbox.com [64.20.227.133]:58085 is not permitted to relay
550 through this server without authentication. [889 ms]

MXTB-PWS3v2 3884ms
```

The error started showing up when I changed the hostname of the server and had the PTR record updated on the host IP. It was showing up as Hivelocity's default PTR and hostname before so I wanted to make sure that it reflected my domain instead of theirs. There has not been any other changes other than what I listed above.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the tests you conduct, those which succeeded and those which didn't as well. What action did you perform that lead to the error you're having? Furthermore, it would be helpful to get informations about your DNS server, and how you set it up.

Comment: @philippe updated my question with more info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got a PTR record mapping 162.254.149.186 to host2.sparkdojo.com, which is fine, But there's no A record for host2.sparkdojo.com, so the lookup the other way is not working. You need both of them to work.

Comment: Ok, so I just updated the DNS records and am waiting for it to propagate. When I run the command `dig host2.sparkdojo.com` I should get back something like `host2.sparkdojo.com    431    A    162.254.149.186` in the answer section right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The forward lookup for the A record has to match the reverse lookup for the PTR record.

Comment: this is the simplest solution on the internet, simply added `host.domain.com. IN A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` for domain.com DNS record and restarted DNS server, it started resolving hostname A record. thanks a lot Sir :)